# proper concatenation for if isset in a php variable string for an HTML input value

Tags: php, html

I have a variable $RepCom if it isset, I want it to be the value of the input RepCom.

I'm trying to figure out the right way to make this work...

```
$x_RepCom = '<input name="RepCom" type="text" value="'. if(isset($RepCom)){echo $RepCom; }.'">';
```

Just dumping the variable is fine, but I get a Undefined error if it is not set.

```
 $x_RepCom = '<input name="RepCom" type="text" value="'.$RepCom.'">';
```

So how do I put the if isset for the $RepCom into the value of the input?

I tryed...

```
$x_RepCom = '<input name="RepCom" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($RepCom)){echo $RepCom; }?>">';
```

But that just dumps the string `<?php if(isset($RepCom)){echo $RepCom; }?>` into the value.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would probably want to put the value as an variable:

```
if(!isset($RepCom))
    $RepCom='';

$x_RepCom = '<input name="RepCom" type="text" value="'.$RepCom.'">';
```

Now if it is not set, it will be given value of an empty string, which will prevent the undefined error.

Comment: what about if I had 50 different variables here? Would I need to do that for each one?

Comment: If you ave an array of variable names you can loop through them and check if(!isset(${$varList[$i]})). However, you can set error reporting to a less strict level to avoid the variable undefined warning.

Answer (score 3):

You had the right idea, you just had the wrong implementation.

```
$RepComPrint = (isset($RepCom)) ? $RepCom : '';
$x_RepCom = '<input name="RepCom" type="text" value="'.$RepComPrint .'">';
```

Comment: you lost me with the ? and : in there. :(

Comment: It's called a [ternary operator](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Answer (score 1):

Are you a functional programmer? The code you wrote (`$x_RepCom = '<input name="RepCom" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($RepCom)){echo $RepCom; }?>">';`) reminds me of how it would be implemented in Scheme or Haskell.

The important thing about PHP is that control structures like `if` it doesn't just return a value; you can't insert it arbitrarily into code.

The way you have to do it in PHP is something like

```
$x_RepCom = '<input name="RepCom" type="text" value="';
if(isset($RepCom)) { $x_RepCom .= $RepCom; }
$x_RepCom .= '>';
```

(Written the long way for clarity)

Comment: I'm very new to programming & php. That's just my way I guess. Thanks for the tip.